# Format date string as per device locale settings

Tags: ios, swift3, localization, nsdate

I have to format the date string (UTC format) as per device locale settings. For example in India it should display as 08/09/2017 12.23 and in US it should display as 09/08/2017 12.23, Based on different region setting it should display the date format accordingly.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The best approach is to not set `dateFormat`, but rather set [`dateStyle`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter/1415411-datestyle) and [`timeStyle`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter/1413467-timestyle).

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
formatter.dateStyle = .medium
formatter.timeStyle = .medium
let string = formatter.string(from: Date())
```

If none of those styles are quite correct, then, go ahead and use `dateFormat`, but rather than a string literal, set `dateFormat` using [`setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter/1417087-setlocalizeddateformatfromtempla).

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
formatter.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("ddMMyyyy HH:mm")
let string = formatter.string(from: Date())
```

That displays `09/08/2017 19:42` for US users, `08/09/2017 19:42` for United Kingdom users, and `08.09.2017 19:42` for German users

Answer (score 1):

The answer of @Rob above didn't work for me, but it showed the right direction. It turned out the [`formatterBehavior`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter/behavior) of the `DateFormatter` instance wasn't set properly (it defaults to [`behavior10_4`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter/behavior/behavior10_4), and not to [`default`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter/behavior/default). This works for me:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.formatterBehavior = .default
dateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium
dateFormatter.timeStyle = .none
let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: Date())
```